# New version of iOS app in App Store can't be upgraded?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have released my app into the app store with an incremented minor version (1.9 -> 1.10). The new version has been 'Ready for sale' for > 1 day.

When I (or others) go to: `itmss://itunes.apple.com/app/{myAppId}?mt=8`. We can see the app, I can see the new version number (1.10) if I scroll down. But the button says 'open' not 'update' (even though i'm clearly on an older version).

If I delete and reinstall the app I get the new version. I've added a mechanism to the app to allow us to make breaking changes and enforce every one is on a certain version of the app (like [Harpy](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy)). But I need them to update it, not reinstall.

Comment: Have you already installed version 1.10 on your device through Xcode? The App Store version won't update if it already see you have 1.10 installed regardless of how it was installed

Comment: In settings of device make sure that date and time settings are automatic.

Comment: 1.10 was not installed in any form.

@Madhu why do date and time settings matter?

Comment: Earlier we faced the same issue but was fixed by changing the date and time settings.  Go through this  http://osxdaily.com/2014/06/05/app-updates-not-showing-app-store-ios-fix/

Comment: @Madhu thanks! Unfortunately, it's not just my phone this issue applies to, but all my users.